# Google App Engine : get_by_id result length?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

How to I return the length of the get_by_id ??

For example I have

```
query = Model.get_by_id(1)
```

I tried

`if len(query) == 1` and `if query.count() == 1` both not working

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***Model.get_by_id()*** returns only a single object if a single id is passed, it returns a list of objects only when a list of id's is passed, which means it obvioulsy won't have **len** and count.

if you want to check if query is not None, you can simply give

```
query=Model.get_by_id(1)

if query is not None:
```

if you want to get a list of objects based on keys, use get:

```
query = MOdel.get(keys) #here keys is a list of keys

if len(query) == 1  will work now
```

Comment: `len(query) == 1` will be True if and only if `len(keys) == 1`, and in particular, even if the single key in the `keys` list doesn't correspond to an actual datastore object.

Answer (score 1):

From http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/modelclass.html#Model_get_by_id:

> If ids is a string representing one name, then the method returns the model instance for the
>   name, or None if the entity doesn't exist. If ids is a list, the method returns a list of
>   model instances, with a None value when no entity exists for a corresponding Key.

So use something like:

```
query = Model.get_by_id(1)
if query is None:
    print 'Not found'
else:
    print 'Returned one result'
```

for multiple ids:

```
query = Model.get_by_id([1, 2, 3])
count = 0
for item in query:
    if item is not None:
        print 'Found item ' + str(item)
        count += 1
print count
```

*Warning: untested*